# finding all subfolder with certain name such that superfolder has certain pattern

Tags: macos, search, terminal

hi all I have a folder that has folders with lots of different names.  However I want to find all the folder that start with `RUN` and have a subfolder of `complete`.  How can I do such a thing in terminal?

Comment: to find folders such as `/Run3289/complete/` and `/Run3221/complete/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mac OS X is UNIX based you can use many terminal programs found on Linux etc. too. Therefore this question is not necessarily OS X related.

Using `find` you can get all your `RUN` folders with a `complete` folder in it:

```
find path_to_your_folder/Run*/complete -maxdepth 0
```

This gives you a list like

```
path_to_your_folder/Run3221/complete
path_to_your_folder/Run3289/complete
```

With ´sed´ you can extract from this the individual folder names:

```
find test/Run*/complete -maxdepth 0 | sed 's/.*\(Run[0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

which gives you a list like you're looking for:

```
Run3221
Run3289
```